# File open prompt Function code not working - don't know why

Tags: excel, file, vba, import, prompt

I have a Sub ImportTest1() which calls in Function files(path). The import sub seems to be working ok but I can't be certain because the Function part does not work when it comes to setting the QueryTable stuff for opening a textfile into the excel worksheet. Code below is what I have at the moment (part in bold is the bit that isn't working) and I'm not sure what it is that is wrong.

```
Sub ImportTest1()

Dim path As String

'CALL TO OPEN FILE DIALOG BOX
path = opener()
If path = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

'CALL TO FILE OPEN FUNCTION
files (path)

End Sub

Function opener()

Dim sFile As String

With UserForm1.CommonDialog1
.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*"
.ShowOpen
If Len(.FileName) = 0 Then
    Exit Function
End If
sFile = .FileName
End With
Unload UserForm1

opener = sFile

End Function

Function files(path As String)

Workbooks.OpenText FileName:="prt.", Origin:=xlWindows, StartRow:=2, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

End Function
```

Comment: Doesn't your `FieldInfo` need to take an array of two-dimensional arrays? I could be wrong, but I think you need `FieldInfo:Array(Array(0,1), Array(1,1), Array(2,1), etc.` At a minimum I would think you would need it to be `Array(1,2,3, etc.)` instead of `Array(1,1,1,...)`.

Comment: when I used the record macro to find what the prt. file array was and looked at that part of it that was what I got...

Comment: You said the line of code that gets the error is in bold, but I can't see the bold. What does the error say exactly?

Comment: Also, it looks like you are getting the file path and name from `opener()` and then passing the result, `path`, to `files(path)`, but you don't use `path` in it. Did you mean to have `FileName:=path` instead of `FileName:="prt."`?

Comment: oh, im just using the original macro on this part but because of changing the file to a variable selection im not sure... so is the path a copy of the selected file's location??

Comment: I tried changing the "prt." to just path but that is even worse. And I don't know why I have sFile = .FileName and then opener =sFile???

Comment: Is all you want to do is have code that opens a file from a given file path and name?

Comment: Mostly yes but because the filename can be anything and the file can be anywhere on the C: drive then it is kind of complicated

Comment: It looks like you are trying to get the file name and path from a user form. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeh but I don't even know what that is. This project began because the original macro wasn't doing things as required and that is the first VBA code I have ever worked on... hence lots of confusion and questions on my part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplify your code a great deal and just deal with what it is you want to achieve. From what I can tell in your previous comments and original post is that you wan to **A.** retrieve a file name and path from the user. You can do that with the following

```
f = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter a file path and name.")
```

This causes a dialog box to pop up where a user can enter some text. What is stored in f will be a string that represents the file name and path. The user can, for instance, type in something like `C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\myFile.csv`.

If you want to open that file that is stored in f, you can try something like what you already have in your post

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=f, DataType:=xlDelimited, Comma:=True, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1,1), Array(2,1), Array(3,1))
```

This assumes a 3 column comma-delimited file was input, but you can modify it to be whatever you like.

All together, you might just need these four lines of vba code to accomplish what you want to accomplish. You can just put it into a subroutine (not a function), like so

```
Sub OpenMyFile()
f = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter a file path and name.")
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=f, DataType:=xlDelimited, Comma:=True, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1,1), Array(2,1), Array(3,1))
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
end sub
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: ah thanks that is so much easier. Does that need the file path entered rather than the file selected? Just to clarify and what is f defined as: String or Long or something else?

Comment: Notice I edited to correct a typo, so use edited version. This little bit of code assumes that the user will enter the entire path AND file name together in one string. See my example: `C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\myFileName.csv`.

Comment: just Filename:=f then? I thought this would be so much more complicated, VBA has annoyed me these past weeks :) thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, Filename:=f. Of course, I am not quite clear on the exact nature of the file you're trying to open. My example is a `.csv` file, so you will have to modify the specs to accept the file you are trying to open.

Comment: it is a type of text file they are usually called "prt#." there is no .txt at the end. When I manually copy in the data I have to select 'All File' types in order to select the required file. Do I enter just the file name into the inputbox or the entire path. I tried the entire path but that did not work

Comment: You should need the entire path. What kind of file is it? It's odd to have a file name end with a `.`.

Comment: This is what I have: 
Sub FileImport()

f = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the file path and name")

Workbooks.OpenText FileName:=f, DataType:=xlDelimited, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, Space:=True, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

End Sub

Comment: they open up in notepad but there are a type of textfile which is what I don't understand. Type = File in the Properties

Comment: Can you try to change the `FieldInfo` to `FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1,1), Array(2,1), Array(3,1), Array(4,1), Array(5,1), Array(6,1))` and see if that makes any difference? What kind of file is this? TXT? CSV?

Comment: Then the file probably needs a .txt extension. So you can try `prt#.txt` after the file path. You can right click on the file and look at properties to see what the extension should be, just to be sure (look at type of file).

Comment: ahhh it does it now but it opens into a new workbook and i want it to paste into the active workbook Sheet1 RangeA1?

Comment: I just edited my answer to add two lines of code that will do that.

Comment: Thanks so much for that :) thought I'd never get it